# how to get value thats displayed in the Emulator?

Tags: java, android

I am writing a small android "Hello world" application and i would really like to write a small test case . i have written a small test case , have a look below :

```
public void testMyFirstTestTextView_labelText() {
    final String expected = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
    final String actual = getContext().getText().toString();
    assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

the `expected` variable gets instantiated with the value from strings.xml
but for the `actual` value , i am struggling to understand what methods or snippet i should write in order to get the value of the displayed string .

so how do i get the value of the text displayed in the emulator: 
as of now the below statement is wrong:

```
final String actual = getContext().getText().toString();
```

i am really new to android , can somebody help me with this please .

if you check the last peice of code in the snippet :

```
assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

it checks(using jUnit i think) weather the value of `expected` is the same as `actual`.

once again to repeat my question in the above snippet , how do i get/retrive the value of the displayed text ? I.E. on the below line :

```
final String actual = getContext().getText().toString();
```

Comment: r u displayed the value in label?

Comment: it should be `yourTextViewObject.getText()` not `getContext().getText()`

Comment: @RishadAppat yes its a label , like so ` <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />`

Comment: @Tenali_raman It should even have a `android:id` entry.

Answer (score 2):

it should be `yourTextViewObject.getText()` not `getContext().getText()`

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_world);//Assuming your id in the xml page is textView1
String actual = textView.getText().toString();
```

This gets the value of an entry `hello_world` from `strings.xml`.

```
String expected = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
```

And This gets the value from the `TextView`.

```
String actual = textView.getText().toString();
```

**From the android documentation's [example](https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html)**

```
mFirstTestText = (TextView) mFirstTestActivity
                .findViewById(R.id.my_first_test_text_view);
 String actual = mFirstTestText.getText().toString();
```

Comment: do i have to replace `textView` in this line `String actual = textView.getText().toString();`

Comment: Yes replace it with your `textView` object name.

Comment: here is the code form my activity_main.xml http://chopapp.com/#v961672e , i don't see any feild with id ?

Comment: Did you drag and drop the `TextView`? Try that.

Comment: i have the following in my activity_main.xml `<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/hello_world" />`  , how do i referance this in my test file , I.E. how do i get the `actual` value now ? (notice that i hae added the id)

Comment: @Tenali_raman I edited the answer, check the code, use the `android:id` to the `view`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82700/discussion-between-tenali-raman-and-uma-kanth).

Comment: i have the following lines of code
`TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_world);//Assuming your id in the xml page is textView1`
`String actual = textView.getText().toString();`
i get an error on `findViewById`
it says
cannot resolve method `findViewById()`

Answer (score 1):

If your textView is called `label` you can use something like this:

```
String s= label.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a exactly the same example [there](https://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-basic-testing.html) at the `Set Up Your Test Fixture` part. Just analyse the TextView with something like this:

```
final String actual = label.getText().toString();
final String expected = getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);
assertEquals(actual, expected)
```

Comment: i get a error on hover of `label` , i get `cannot resolve symbol label` i have used the same line in your code

Comment: `label` is the name of the `TextView`. Look at the docs they explain better than me....

Comment: where do i get the name of the TextView ?

Comment: You created your `TextView` right? So you can get it with its id that you used when you created it in the `Activity`

Comment: i have posted the code from activity_main here : http://chopapp.com/#v961672e , i don;t see any feild with ID ?

Comment: that's an error then, add `android:id="@+id/theIdYouWant"`to your `TextView`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82698/discussion-between-tenali-raman-and-laurent-meyer).

Comment: i have added the following ` <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/hello_world" />` how do i referance it in my test file though , how do i  `final String actual = label.getText().toString();` , how do i edit label to be the label ?